# Incrementing through IP addresses in String format

Tags: java, string

I'm new to java and i'm trying to find a way of incrementing through an user input IP address range.

For example from `192.168.0.1` to `192.168.0.255`. However the way my application works at the moment is the take the *from* and to *ip* addresses as a `String`.

Is there a way I can increment through all the ip addresses the user input *from* and *to*?

Hope this makes sense and please dont flame me, I have looked for an answer!

EDIT!

Its actually to ping through the address range so, here's a little code so far, the 'host' is being passed in from another class, which i want to cycle through the addresses:

```
    public static String stringPing(String stringPing, String host){

    String ipAddress;
    ipAddress = host;

    try
    {
        InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);

        boolean status = inet.isReachable(2000); 

        if (status)
        {
            stringPing = "\n" +host +" is reachable";
            return stringPing;
        }
        else
        {
            stringPing = "\n" +host +" is unreachable";
            return stringPing;
        }
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Host does not exists");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error in reaching the Host");
    }

    return stringPing;

}
```

Comment: You'd have to show some code if you want people to help out. Your question is also a bit confusing.. what do you mean by "increment through" .. do you mean *iterate* through? If you can guarantee that the user-input is well formed, you can just split it up at the periods and make a number using `parseInt` for example, then just keep going until you reach `255`.

Comment: The from and to addresses are input by the user. I have to find a way to cycle through the range that has been input by the user...

Comment: Please, please see @Dims answer below. It's the proper way to do it and that will work with any IP range (Not just a class C ). An IPv4 address is simply a 4-byte integer in network byte order (big-endian).

Comment: Thanks a million, just looking over some of the answers, Dims looks fit for purpose :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hold address as it should be -- as 32-bit integer, and increment it in this form. Convert it from or to `String` only if required. Example is below. My `IPAddress` class is complete and functional.

```
class IPAddress {

    private final int value;

    public IPAddress(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public IPAddress(String stringValue) {
        String[] parts = stringValue.split("\\.");
        if( parts.length != 4 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        value = 
                (Integer.parseInt(parts[0], 10) << (8*3)) & 0xFF000000 | 
                (Integer.parseInt(parts[1], 10) << (8*2)) & 0x00FF0000 |
                (Integer.parseInt(parts[2], 10) << (8*1)) & 0x0000FF00 |
                (Integer.parseInt(parts[3], 10) << (8*0)) & 0x000000FF;
    }

    public int getOctet(int i) {

        if( i<0 || i>=4 ) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        return (value >> (i*8)) & 0x000000FF;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=3; i>=0; --i) {
            sb.append(getOctet(i));
            if( i!= 0) sb.append(".");
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if( obj instanceof IPAddress ) {
            return value==((IPAddress)obj).value;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public IPAddress next() {
        return new IPAddress(value+1);
    }


}

public class App13792784 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        IPAddress ip1 = new IPAddress("192.168.0.1");

        System.out.println("ip1 = " + ip1);

        IPAddress ip2 = new IPAddress("192.168.0.255");

        System.out.println("ip2 = " + ip2);

        System.out.println("Looping:");

        do {

            ip1 = ip1.next();

            System.out.println(ip1);

        } while(!ip1.equals(ip2));


    }

}
```

Comment: looks like exactly what i needed. I'll report back when I get around to implementing

Comment: @Brian, I disagree. I use only bitwise and shift operators, which are endianness independent. Entire 32-bit integer is a whole binary number with no bytes tagged inside. Byte order is unknown. It will matter if you pass `int` into some third-party network routine, but it will be converted appropriately then since routine should know `int`'s endianness.

Comment: Oh, and +1 by the way - it's the right way to approach this problem.

Comment: @Brian, but where is the swapping code you think? For example, constructor code swaps nothing: leftmost part of IP address (192) goes to leftmost part of parts array (`part[0]`) and then goes to leftmost part of the value (`& 0xFF000000`). Leftmost always remain leftmost, no swapping.

Comment: @Dims - I feel like an idiot - I was obviously past my Beer:SO ratio last night and was completely confusing things in my head ... but kept typing anyway. You're absolutely correct and I deleted my comments. (What was backwards in my head was that you have to convert FROM network byte order to sort IP addresses correctly).

Comment: Dims, I'm having trouble with this as I need the IP address your code returns to be a String. How can I take the new ip address from your code and return it to type String?

Comment: @Matt, it returns `String` representation with `toString()` method.

Comment: Dims, your a genius and dont let anyone tell you otherwise! Thankyou.

Comment: @Dims, can you release this as a jar library? Your own or part of any opensource library? Its highly useful. Also consider adding previous() method also

Comment: @Dims This is extremely useful, but I'm trying to understand why the code is written as it is, specifically the constructor. Why are you adding parts like this: `& 0xFF000000` to the string parser. Doesn't your code work if you just byte shift and add? From my tests, it seems that would work. I'm just trying to understand the decision behind your method.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to just print all from ip + 0...255

```
public void iterateOverIPRange(String ip) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 256) {
        System.out.println(ip + "." + i)
        i++;
    }
}
```

Or if you need from 0 to 255:

```
public String[] iterateOverIPRange(String ip) {
    String[] ips = new ip[255];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 256)) {
        String s = ip + "." + i;
        ips[i] = s;
        i++;
    }
    return ips;
}
```

If you want to specify the range:

```
public String[] iterateOverIPRange(String ip, int from, int to) {
    String[] ips = new ip[to];
    int index = 0;
    while(from < (to + 1)) {
        String s = ip + "." + from;
        ips[index] = s;
        from++;
        index++;
    }
    return ips;
}
```

When you have the `String[]` you can simply iterate through it and ping every single one.

Comment: I think *From* and *To* being `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.0.255` was just an example OP gave.

Comment: There we go. Should now encounter for all 3 things.

Comment: Im not sure any of those fit. I dont think I made myself clear :(. The from and to addresses are input by the user, i need a way to cycle between all addresses in that range. but, the problem i'm facing is that both the from and to are strings. I need a way to hit every address inbetween...

Comment: You just need the base IP as a string, (first 3 parts) and then the last part as an Int. You can change that pretty easily, I am sure. And even if you can't, any of these methods should be fairly easy to change to fit your needs. If you need to extract an integer from a string, you use the `Integer.parseInt(String)`. Just remember that if it doesn't get an Integer to parse, it will throw an unchecked `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't like bit-shifting I made my own IP-iteration construct for a exploit scanner I made once. 
As is, the code just prints the address plus an extra dot. if you uncomment the ping utility or port-scanner it works fine for that too.

sorry for some of the sub-optimal variable names and broad exceptions, I wrote this on the fly out of memory of a neater class I once wrote. It's just to show that Java does enable us to iterate through a larger range of IPs then just 1 subnet without using bit-shifting.

```
package com.cybergrinder.core;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        // get input from somewhere, in this case we use the scanner for convenience and testing
        // try for example with 192.0.0.0 and 192.255.255.255 to scan the entire 192-B ranges
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("start part of the address");
        String rangeStart = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("end part of the address");
        String rangeEnd = scanner.nextLine();

        int[] startAdrElements = new int[4];
        int[] endAdrElements = new int[4];

        // System.out.println(rangeStart.split("\\.")[0]);

        int startA1 = (Integer.parseInt(rangeStart.split("\\.")[0]));
        int startB1 = (Integer.parseInt(rangeStart.split("\\.")[1]));
        int startC1 = (Integer.parseInt(rangeStart.split("\\.")[2]));
        int startD1 = (Integer.parseInt(rangeStart.split("\\.")[3]));
        int endA = (Integer.parseInt(rangeEnd.split("\\.")[0]));
        int endB = (Integer.parseInt(rangeEnd.split("\\.")[1]));
        int endC = (Integer.parseInt(rangeEnd.split("\\.")[2]));
        int endD = (Integer.parseInt(rangeEnd.split("\\.")[3]));

        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0; // args to work with after itteration proces
        for (int startA = startA1; startA <= endA; startA++) {// max 255.255.255.255, could implement sanitisation later..

            a = startA;

            for (int startB = startB1; startB <= endB; startB++) {

                b = startB;

                for (int startC = startC1; startC <= endC; startC++) {

                    c = startC;

                    for (int startD = startD1; startD <= endD; startD++) {

                        d = startD;

                        // convert intArray to byteArray
                        int[] intArray = new int[] { a, b, c, d };
                        String address = "";
                        for (int e : intArray) {
                            address += e + ".";
                        }

                        try {
                            System.out.println(address);

                            // enable pinging
                            /*
                            address = address.substring(0, (address.length() - 1));
                            InetAddress ipBytes = InetAddress.getByName(address);
                            boolean up = false;
                            up = ipBytes.isReachable(500);

                            if (up == true) {
                                System.out.println("host at " + ipBytes + " is up");
                            }
                            */

                            // enable portscanning
                            /*
                             * int port = 80; Socket sock = new Socket();
                             * sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipBytes,
                             * port), 2000); //if it does not connect flow
                             * goes to catch System.out.println(port +"/tcp"
                             * + " is open ");
                             */

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            // e.printStackTrace(); System.out.println("host
                            // is down");

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Simple Logic. Up to 4 billion (4228250625) IPs we can generate using the below logic(0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255)**

```
public class IpGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int totalIP = 50000;//Set the total IPs to be generated
        String startIP= "10.10.1.1"; // Set the IP start range
        int A = Integer.parseInt(startIP.split("\\.")[0]);
        int B = Integer.parseInt(startIP.split("\\.")[1]);
        int C = Integer.parseInt(startIP.split("\\.")[2]);
        int D = Integer.parseInt(startIP.split("\\.")[3]);
        int total=0;
        while (total<=totalIP) {
            total++;
            if(255>D) {D++;}
            else {D=0;
                if(255>C) {C++;}
                else {C=0;
                    if(255>B) {B++;}
                    else {B=0;
                        if(255>A) {A++;}
                        else {
                            throw new Exception("IP LIMIT EXCEEDED !!!!!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            String IP=A+"."+B+"."+C+"."+D;
            System.out.println("IP:"+IP);
        }
    }
}
Sample 
--------
...............
...............
...............
IP:10.10.193.251
IP:10.10.193.252
IP:10.10.193.253
IP:10.10.193.254
IP:10.10.193.255
IP:10.10.194.0
IP:10.10.194.1
IP:10.10.194.2
IP:10.10.194.3
IP:10.10.194.4
...............
...............
...............
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make the end digit an integer, and increment it as you go along.

```
public String strIp = "192.168.0.";
public Sting ip;

for (int x = 1; x == 255, x++) {
    ip = strIp+x;
}
```

Comment: I think *From* and *To* being `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.0.255` was just an example OP gave